# Strange Behavior when updating hash with default proc using +=

Tags: ruby, hash

Why is this hash:

```
test_hash = Hash.new{|hash, key|
              Hash.new{|second_level_hash, second_level_key| 0 }
            }
```

not updated by the following operation?

```
test_hash[1][1] += 1
test_hash[1][1] # => 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually assigning the value to the Hash, you're just returning a Hash and an independent 0 value. These get modified, then thrown away.

Fix this by performing an assignment:

```
test_hash = Hash.new { |h,k|
  h[k] = Hash.new(0)
}
```

You can tell something was wrong because after accessing `test_hash[1][1]` then calling `test_hash.inspect` it's still empty.

Comment: The `Hash.new` block is called each time a new key is populated and while you're not obligated to do anything to the hash, usually it's a good idea to alter it. Unless you call `h[k] = ...` or something like that your values are independent of the hash and aren't saved.

Comment: Thanks!

Why does this work?

    test_hash = Hash.new{|h, k| [] }
    test_hash +=  ['something']

Comment: I get "undefined method `+' for {}:Hash (NoMethodError)", which is not surprising. That shouldn't work.

Comment: If you mean `test_hash[1] += [ 'test' ]` then I presume it's because this also calls `test_hash[1] = [ 'test' ]` which forces a direct assignment. Your two level version can't benefit from this quirk.

Comment: Typo, I meant: test_hash = Hash.new{|h, k| [] } test_hash[1] += ['something']

Comment: Note that `test_hash[1] << 'test'` doesn't work because the assignment operator is not involved. Your implementation only works by coincidence. The correct way to do it is to force an assignment in the block, that way values are always nailed down.

Comment: Hope that explains it! Sometimes stuff in Ruby sort of kind of not quite works and it can be really confusing if you don't know the reason why.

Comment: The inner hash construction can simply be `Hash.new(0)`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Not sure why I didn't do that in the first place. Adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

tadman's answer is (halfway) correct, but may be a bit misleading.

You are assigning a value to the embedded hash, but not assigning the embedded hash to the main hash. Each time a key is called in the main hash, a new embedded hash is created. After you have assigned a value to the embedded hash, the embedded hash that has become `{1 => 1}` is not assigned to the main hash, and is thrown away.